# What are side effects of disabling LINT inspection?

Tags: java, android, manifest, lint

Actually, my application was not running, So I Click on "Disable Inspection", after that, it starts running Swiftly. Now, Is there can be any Upcoming Problem in App?

[image]

Comment: was my answer helpful

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the Lint(static code analysis tool in android)checking at different levels, **By clicking disable inspection in the above the lint inspection for the entire project is disabled**
Other level of lint options can be read here 
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html#config
**ALSO IT IS HIGHLY RECOMMENDED TO USE LINT**